# Forecasting in FB Prophet by Minute

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima, facebook-prophet

I'm attempting to do minute forecasting using Prophet.  But I'm getting strange output.  Any suggestions on how to forecast by minute in Prophet or suggestions for improving my code would be very appreciated!

Data is in format for FB Prophet.

```
df_min.head()
    ds  y
0   2020-01-17 14:21:00     166.380
1   2020-01-17 14:22:00     166.335
2   2020-01-17 14:23:00     166.315
3   2020-01-17 14:24:00     166.320
4   2020-01-17 14:25:00     166.355
```

There are 100 minutes within the df_min dataframe.  Below, breaking out 30 minutes for the train_df_min dataframe...

```
prediction_size = 30
train_df_min = df_min[:-prediction_size]
```

Now attempting the forecast...

```
q = Prophet(daily_seasonality=True)
q.fit(train_df_min)

future2 = q.make_future_dataframe(periods=60, freq='1min')
forecast2 = q.predict(future2)
forecast2.tail()
```

[image]

And the chart output...

[image]

Comment: You apply ARIMA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your minute data into hour,weekly,monthly,etc.. then compare accuracy, take the frequency which is giving more accurate forecast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any frequency from `pd.date_range`
see prophet documentaion in github

`freq: Any valid frequency for pd.date_range, such as 'D' or 'M'`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases

For example, this is for 15min forecasting intervals:

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=10, freq='0.25H')
```